# How to export to csv with al values in quotes with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a module that needs `csv` data where all values are quoted. How can I export a `pandas.DataFrame()` such that the values are always in quotes (`"`)?

The docstring only says:

> quotingoptional constant from csv module
> Defaults to csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL. If you have set a float_format then floats are converted to strings and thus csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC will treat them as non-numeric.

Maybe something like csv.QUOTE_MAXIMAL?

Comment: If you found an answer that works, please add a response and accept it so other readers can benefit.

Comment: Cannot accept the answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.to_csv(..., quote=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```